# Java NullPointerException but String is not empty

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception, content-management-system, opencms

I'm currently working on a class which writes Values into CmsXmlContent and saves them as a file.
I've got many variables and it's working very well but one String seems to hate me...
It returns a NullPointerException everytime.

I tried to wrote it but seriously I'm checking if the String is null AND printing it out with perfect results just a line above.

So hopefully you can help me out :)

Expose:

```
public class Expose {
    private String address, bid, build, corridorNumber, corridorPiece, county,
        floor, form, houseType, mark, number, partner, price, registry,
        roofAngle, size, status, title, view, width;
    private List<String> features, infra, location, media, region, use,
        useType;
    private List<byte[]> documents, images;
    private List<ExposeAbsatz> paragraphs;

    // getters and setters
}
```

ExposeAbsatz:

```
public class ExposeAbsatz {
    private String content, headline;
    private byte[] image;

    // getters and setters
}
```

My Code:

```
Locale de = Locale.GERMAN;
CmsXmlContent xmlContent = CmsXmlContentFactory.createDocument(cms,
        de, "UTF-8", CmsXmlContentDefinition.getContentDefinitionForType(cms, "expose"));
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(thisExpose.getTitle()))
    xmlContent.getValue("/titel", de).setStringValue(cms,
            StringUtils.stripToEmpty(thisExpose.getTitle()));
// works
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(thisExpose.getNumber()))
    xmlContent.getValue("/properties/number", de).setStringValue(
                    cms, StringUtils.stripToEmpty(thisExpose.getNumber()));
// works as well
if (thisExpose.getParagraphs() != null) {
    int i = 0;
    for (ExposeAbsatz currentExposeAbsatz : thisExpose.getParagraphs()) {
    String headline = StringUtils.stripToEmpty(currentExposeAbsatz.getHeadline());
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(headline)) {
            System.out.println("headline[" + i + "] = " + headline);
            // headline[0] = aasd
            // absatz is minOccurs="4" maxOccurs="5"
            xmlContent.getValue("/absatz[" + i + "]/ueberschrift", de)
                                .setStringValue(cms, headline); // NullPointerException
            (...)
        }
        (...)
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Do you? At the very bottom of the answer to the linked question, there is a section on debugging null-pointer exceptions.

Comment: Probably this is returning null: `xmlContent.getValue("/absatz[" + i + "]/ueberschrift", de)` but you havent given enough info to know for sure

Comment: he said the cms variable is returning null; I don't see where it's ever initialized though.

Comment: Either `xmlContent` or `xmlContent.getValue("/absatz[" + i + "]/ueberschrift", de)` is `null`. You need to debug it.

Comment: Max, does the `NullPointerException` tell you what line your program is failing at? That would probably help.

Comment: updated.
Note:
NullPointerException occurs on the line where ".setStringValue(cms, headline);" is written.